# Why is pyautogui.locateOnScreen("1.png") throwing an error whenever it cannot see it?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying out some python image recognition, but whenever the image is not on the screen it throws an error, instead of going into the else statement. Is there a way to fix that that does not involve using try / except?

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui

while True:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("1.png", confidence=0.9) != None:
        print("I can see it")
        time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        print("I cannot see it")
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: _it throws an error_ It would help if you showed the error, instead of making us guess what it says.

Comment: ```try``` ```except``` instead in this instance.

Comment: (Wildcard imports, on the other hand, *are* considered bad practice. Yours is unused in this code.)

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("1.png", confidence=0.9) != None:`, what do you expect this to mean? When `pyautogui.locateOnScreen("1.png", confidence=0.9)` happens, why should the result ever be `None`? Did you **read the documentation**, in order to check if it works that way?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions) says that

> As of version 0.9.41, if the locate functions can’t find the provided image, they’ll raise `ImageNotFoundException` instead of returning `None`.

Exceptions on failed operations are pretty normal in Python, and catching them doesn’t make bad code.

```
import pyautogui

while True:
    try:
        pyautogui.locateOnScreen("1.png", confidence=0.9)
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
        print("I cannot see it")
    else:
        print("I can see it")

    time.sleep(0.5)
```

You can also wrap this in your own function that returns `None` on an `ImageNotFoundException`. But to answer your question as stated, there is a PyAutoGUI builtin that won’t throw when it doesn’t find an image: `locateAllOnScreen`. It produces a generator, which you can pass to `next` along with a default.

```
import pyautogui

while True:
    if next(pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen("1.png", confidence=0.9), None) is not None:
        print("I can see it")
    else:
        print("I cannot see it")

    time.sleep(0.5)
```